# How to call java methods in a dynamic order?

Tags: java, function, inheritance, methods, program-entry-point

Okay, I'll try being as specific as I can.

I have a main class **InputHandler** and around five methods under it. Then I have six other classes with each class having around ten methods under it. Each of the class has its own main method which calls the method in **that particular** class in an order. Note that each class other than inputHandler has a variable called priority which stores an integer from 0 to 10.

For example,

```
    class helloWorld
    {
        String name; int age;
        int priority = 2;
        public static void main()
        {
            setName("John");
            setAge(32);
        }

        public static void setName(String n)
        {
            name = n;
        }

        public static void setAge(int a)
        {
            age = a;
        }
    }
```

And other similar classes.

But the main class is an extension of all other classes.
So the order would look similar to:

helloWorld > helloCountry > helloTown > inputHandler **(where a > b means that b extends a)**

So this will ensure all the methods of the previous classes are inherited in inputHandler.

Now, as I said, the inputHandler class itself has its own main method. So, if I want to call a method which belongs to one of the upperclasses I could use something like:

```
...

public static void main()
{
      helloTown.main();
      helloWorld.main();
      helloCountry.main();
}

...
```

Now this is my question: How do I call the respective main methods using the inputHandler in the order of the priority. For example, if helloWorld has priority 2 and helloTown has 1 and helloCountry 3,  then helloTown.main() should be called first, then helloWorld.main() and last helloCountry.main().

I know this sounds a bit confusing, but I'm sure it can be done. My take on this was to first extract the priority value of the variable and arrange it in an ascending order, and make the method calls as required. Any help is appreciated! Please feel free to ask me further details! Thank you in advance.

Comment: What? You want to call helloTown first then you already did. Java runs code in order... and is blocking unless  you thread it out. And is this one program is so why do you have so many main methods... If you want to dynamically load classes use classloader

Comment: When you write code which calls methods in a specific order, that is the order they are called. This is what you have done.  Can you clarify what you would like to do differently?

Comment: Side note: your design seems very odd. You have instance variables e.g. `name` but _static_ setters? Won't work that way. You're calling `main()` instead of a constructor? Why?

Comment: Actually, the program is really big, I just posted a smaller version of it. I am aware that Java executes program in order but that is what I want to change. If a extends b, and b extends c, I want to change the way the respective main methods are called. Instead of implicitly typing them line by line, I want it to be automatically prioritized and executed. Much similar to what @Thomas answered.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure I get your question correctly but I'll try:

**Inheritance**

If you have a hierarchy where C extends B and B extends A you could do the following with instance methods:

```
class A {
  void someMethod() { ... }
}

class B extends A {
  void someMethod() { 
    super.someMethod(); //calls the method from A
    //do whatever B needs to do here
  }
}

class C extends B {
  void someMethod() { 
    //let's change order and first do what C needs to do
    super.someMethod(); //calls the method from B       
  }
}
```

As you can see, with `super` you can call methods of the class that is being extended and you can do (almost) any order you like (in this case it would be logic of C then A then B).

**Priority**

Since you mentioned priority I assume you want to have different objects, all with a potentially different priority.

In that case you either could store the priority externally or in the object itself (via methods, fields, annotations etc.).

Addionally you might want to provide a common interface with a method that can be called, e.g. like this (I'll add a method for getting the priority):

```
interface CommonInterface {
  void someMethod();

  //one way you could do this
  int getPriority();
}

class A implements CommonInterface {
  void someMethod() { ... }

  int getPriority() { return 1; }
}

//same for B and C
```

Then you get some collection, e.g. a list, sort it and iterate:

```
List<CommonInterface> list = ...;
list.add( new A() );
list.add( new B() );
list.add( new C() );

//sort the list, I'll leave the implementation of the comparator for you
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<CommonInterface>() { 
  public int compare( CommonInterface o1, CommonInterface o2) {
    //compare both objects' priority as needed
    //for more information have a look at the JavaDoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)
  }
} );

//iterate and call the method
for( CommonInterface instance : list ) {
  instance.someMethod();
}
```

Comment: I don't really like inheritance for this; what if there's a `setPopulation(...)` method and you want different population counts for world/country/state/city?

Comment: @yshavit of course inheritance would not be the logical choice for cities, countries, world etc. but `InputHandler` wouldn't fit in there either. That's why I was keeping my answer abstract and that's why I mentioned interfaces in the second part.

Comment: helloWorld and helloCountry were just example names. I totally understand the use of `super` but can you please elaborate on the priorities part? I'm not an expert on java... so I need help with the `Comparator<CommonInterface>()` part. Thanks a lot! I think you have solved most of the problems!

Comment: @AekanshDixit I added a stub for the relevant method, the implementation isn't that hard and you should be able to get it done after reading the JavaDoc. It's meant as a learning excercise :)

Comment: Also, where will I put the code for the list... inside the interface you just defined or inputHandler? I'm sorry for the naming conventions, it was just spontaneous.

Comment: @AekanshDixit no the interface won't know anything of that list. Normally you'd put the list to some central class - which one would depend on your actual architecture and your needs (might be the one with the `main()` method or some other class). It's hard to provide advice here without knowing more and it would probably be way out of scope anyways.

Comment: @AekanshDixit you might be able to get this done with reflection (using annotations or naming conventions) but I'd suggest not to use that unless you really need to and absolutely know what you're doing. What's the problem with interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

In inputHandler's main method,

get the priorities of other instances, as `helloCountry.getPriority()` and

then save all the priorities in a hash, list or some other DS.

Then sort the DS and you can call the main methods accordingly!

Thomas' method is better, unless the priorities are defined at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If the priorities are not known until runtime, this becomes a really wacky question... but you could try using reflection, perhaps a Map<Integer, Class> which would hold a mapping of the priority value to the Class.

Suppose World=0, Country=1, Town=2

```
    // Initialize the map
    Map<Integer, Class<?>> callPrio = new HashMap<Integer, Class<?>>();
    callPrio.put(helloWorld.value, helloWorld.class);
    callPrio.put(helloCountry.value, helloCountry.class);
    callPrio.put(helloTown.value, helloTown.class);

    // Invoke "main" methods in order of priority
    for (int i = 0; i < callPrio.size(); i++)
        callPrio.get(i).getMethod("main").invoke(null);
```

This code would invoke main methods in this order at runtime:

```
helloWorld.main()
helloCountry.main()
helloTown.main()
```

Comment: I find this method usefull too! Thanks for the answer!